# Are both ground pins on the ATMEGA internally connected?

Tags: arduino, atmega

I think the title is self-explanatory but should I make the connection on PCB or they are already connected? If so, should I still connect them externally? Why?

I'm working on ATMEGA328p-pu if it matters.

[image: atmega]
<sub>(source: [instructables.com](https://cdn.instructables.com/F2S/FHSD/H3Z3V3P4/F2SFHSDH3Z3V3P4.MEDIUM.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Not the same, but thx. Now I already know that I must connect them, but still not if they're internally connected.

Comment: As Olin says in the link, it's really hard to say - whether or not there's an internal connection probably depends on the chip.

Comment: So, should I delete the topic?

Comment: Whether they are internally connected or not is not your concern. You need to connect them both anyway, so what does it matter if they are internally connected or not?

Comment: Wouldn't 30 seconds with an ohmmeter answer the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no internal connection. One ground is Digital ground, the other Analog Ground, and they should be connected through an inductor capacitor circuit for best performance. I know this is a dupe of a Avr specific question I answered too